# How to force a LocalJumpError on return in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My function `bar` gets a block, and I'd like to run this block without allowing it to `return`. How do I do that by modifying only `bar` below, and keeping everything else, including `foo`, intact?

```
def bar()
  yield
end
def foo()
  bar do
    p "it"
    return  # This works. But I'd like to get LocalJumpError.
  end
end
foo
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: I'd like to emulate `Fiber` in Ruby 1.8, and `Fiber.new { ... }` doesn't support `return` -- so the emulation mustn't support it either. By the way, I've given up on emulation (both with `callcc` and `Thread`), because I could write it so it wouldn't leak memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions in other answers, I have managed to solve the problem:

```
def bar()
  has_returned = true
  begin
    x = yield
    has_returned = false
    x
  rescue
    has_returned = false
    raise
  ensure
    raise LocalJumpError if has_returned
  end
end
def foo()
  bar do
    p "it"
    return  # This makes bar raise a LocalJumpError.
  end
end
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Well, you get a `LocalJumpError` when you try and pass a block with a `return` to a `Proc` (as opposed to a `lambda`).</strike>

You can get away with not changing `foo` except for how it's called, if you do something like

```
def bar()
  Proc.new
end

def foo()
  bar do
    p "it"
    return
  end
end

foo[]
```

That gives a `LocalJumpError`.

Anyway, [this article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) might help.

Edit: A `return` in a proc will return from the outer method, not from the anonymous method in the block. You might be able to set a flag that you can check in `bar` to see if it returned prematurely:

```
bar_finished = false

def bar(&block)
  proc = Proc.new &block
  l.call
  bar_finished = true
end
```

Then, if a `return` is in the block passed to `bar`, `bar_finished` will still be false. Not sure if adding a non-local variable like this is an option, but if so, you could track returns from the block and throw whatever exception you want if it happens.

Comment: Although your answer is insightful, it does not answer my question. In my question, there was a requirement of not changing anything else outside `bar`. And you have posted an answer which changes `foo` to `foo[]`. Do you have a solution which changes only `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

If there's some "cleaning up" code you want done after `yield`, then you may want to use `begin` and then `ensure`.

Comment: What you write is correct, but I fail to see why it is relevant to my question.

Comment: You didn't explain why you wanted it done - I based my answer on the best guess as to why you were doing it.